# How to Lump in Validation Rules With Aurelia When Clause

Tags: javascript, validation, aurelia

I am currently trying to validate a form where input is based on whether a checkbox is checked or not.

```
.ensure(p => p.receiverFixFee).required().when(n => n.chargeReceiver === true)
    .satisfies(a => (Number(a) > 0))
```

In this example, if the Charge Receiver box is checked, then the input needs to be required and must be above 0. I have moved the when clause around and have not been able to ensure that both of these conditions are met. How can I make sure that required and satisfies are both attached the .when()?

Comment: It seems to work fine for me, can you help with a reproduction? https://codesandbox.io/s/httpsstackoverflowcomquestions60007558how-to-lump-in-validation-rules-with-aurelia-when-clause-49wg0